# Selecting Radio Button using JQuery only shows change after page refresh

Tags: jquery, radio-button, mustache

I have this page setup using mustache, within my page there are radio buttons. If I use

```
$('input:radio[name=gender]')[0].checked = true;
```

of any of the methods shown [here](http://www.mkyong.com/jquery/how-to-select-a-radio-button-with-jquery/), nothing works unless I reload my page. My Jquery block is also within `jQuery(document).ready(function() {` tags.

What could be the problem, is there a way I can refresh the radio buttons?

Comment: Could you provide a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) reproducing the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah I do not know why it is not mentioned in more places but I had a similar problem with a drop down not doing what I wanted. I am guessing you are having the same problem based on the link to the methods you were trying. Try this.

```
   $('input:radio[name=sex]:nth(0)').attr('checked',true).change();
```

The only difference being the .change();